# How to convert for each loop over objects list property into linq statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

how to you put this loop into a one line linq statement using a where clause.

```
 Role role = db.Roles.Find(id);
 List<User> users = new List<User>();
 foreach (var usr in db.Users.ToList())
 {
   if (usr.Roles != null)
   {
     if (usr.Roles.Contains(role)) users.Add(usr);
   }
 }
```

Comment: I think Sergey's (currently-deleted) answer was almost correct - I think it just needed the `ToList()` on `db.Users.ToList()`, i.e. `var users = db.Users.ToList().Where(u => u.Roles != null && u.Roles.Contains(role)).ToList();` to make it work with Linq-to-Entities. But then the `ToList()` is going to copy all the users out the DB.

Comment: Yes it works.  Thanks Matthew. But I am loading the whole collection into memory by using ToList()

Comment: @MatthewWatson I deleted it because moving entire collection to memory is very bad practice. Also you need to include Roles into the result set to avoid huge number of lazy-load requests

Comment: @GlutVonSmark what type is `role`?  and did you override `Equals` method of this class? I.e. how do you compare two instances of roles? Should they have same id or same name?

Comment: I would advice you to use Resharper. It can help you by writing better code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
List<User> users  = db.Users.Where(user => user.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == role)).ToList();
```

This is the case if you want to compare role names otherwise implement your `Equal` method

Comment: I thought `Role` was a simple primitive string but in your case you seems to get role name from role. Look now because it is edited

Comment: Thanks. Used db ID instead of Name but same idea

Answer (score 0):

Here's your answer, but you should avoid using Contains and instead filter on an Id for example to gain performances.

```cs
// Solution 1
List<User> users = db.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Contains(role)).ToList();

// Solution 2
List<User> users = db.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.Id == role.Id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

You must define the list of possible roles before. And by calling Contains EF generates an  IN (...) clause.

```
var roles = new[] {"Role1", "Role2"};
var users = db.Users.Where(u => u.Roles != null && roles.Contains(u.Roles));
```

Comment: I don't think `Roles` is a collection of strings

Comment: So it is not clear what user.Roles is and what role is used to compare.

Comment: Not my downvote, but the explanation is my - you cannot have a collection of primitives in EF entity